# Setting up SMTP server for your app in a container

Tags: email, docker, smtp, docker-container

I have an app which sends email and requires smtp running on port 25. For which I created another container and mapped port 25 from host to container.

That didnt quite work well, as it kept throwing the following error

`ERROR: for smtp  Cannot start service smtp: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint push_smtp_1 (25f260f6185dd34cfdb8fb9956c28187028aaca4d850d7a73acc4c2180c55696): Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:25: unexpected error (Failure EADDRINUSE)`

Not sure what could be wrong here, following the other posts I tried restarting the docker client, as well as verified that there is nothing else running on port 25 `lsof -i:25` Let me know if I am missing something here.

The 2nd part to this question is, what is the Ideal way to deal with smtp server.

1. Should the smtp server be created within the app container. Came across this blog http://www.tothenew.com/blog/setting-up-sendmail-inside-your-docker-container/
2. If not (1), then is it better to create a smtp container and map ports.Is so, whats the reason for getting the above error.

Below is how my docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  push:
    image: emailService
    ports:
    - "9602:9602/tcp"
    networks:
    - default
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
      - "TARGET=build"
    depends_on:
    - gearmand
    - smtp
  smtp:
    image: catatnight/postfix:latest
    ports:
    - "25:25"
    networks:
    - default
  gearmand:
    image: <path>/<to>/gearmand:latest
    ports:
    - "4730:4730/tcp"
    networks:
    - default
```

Thanks!

Comment: You don’t map ports “from the host to the container”; it’s always in the other direction.  The container can just make ordinary TCP connections to the host’s IP address; or (probably better in this case) to some off-box trusted SMTP server.

Comment: Thanks for the clearing my understanding. but can you give more insights on what you meant by  `or (probably better in this case) to some off-box trusted SMTP server.`

Comment: If you’re, say, already a Google user, it’s better to use Google’s SMTP server, because my mail client will probably flag an `@gmail.com` address as spam if it’s coming from somewhere else.

Comment: Is it even necessary to map the port? With the right configuration, containers can reach each other without publishing the port.

Comment: @user1666456 thanks! I believe me configuring it explicitly was conflicting with the default setting. Worked well when I remove the ports configuration.

Comment: @Gayatri Great. I don't know why it would conflict. I wrote a more elaborate answer in case someone has the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the SMTP server to just be reachable from the other container and not from the outside, no need to map the port.

Using docker-compose, all defined containers will automatically be added to a network in which containers can reach each other by their name (see https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/). If your custom "default" network is a bridge network, this will work as well.

That means, your SMTP container will directly be reachable at `smtp:25` from other containers (i.e. its internal port and internal hostname instead of the host port and publicly routable IP address of your docker host).

Nobody else will be able to use your SMTP server like that. I think this might lead to problems with recipients not accepting the emails sent by it (see https://serverfault.com/q/364473). @David Maze has a point in saying that it's probably better to use a public/official mail provider anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you have something else on the host that is already listening on that port

Try to find out what ports on the host are listening with  https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-find-out-what-ports-are-listeningopen-on-my-linuxfreebsd-server/

Comment: I tried checking and there seems nothing listening on that port.Just to be sure I also did this `lsof -ti:3000 | xargs kill` I also tried connecting locally via `telnet localhost 25` and it did connect. But somehow via docker it continues to give that error.

Answer (score 0):

Use some other port on the host:

```
version: '3'
services:
  push:
    image: emailService
    ports:
    - "9602:9602/tcp"
    networks:
    - default
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
      - "TARGET=build"
    depends_on:
    - gearmand
    - smtp
  smtp:
    image: catatnight/postfix:latest
    ports:
    - "2525:25"
    networks:
    - default
  gearmand:
    image: <path>/<to>/gearmand:latest
    ports:
    - "4730:4730/tcp"
    networks:
    - default
```